# chainerを用いてcaffemodelで推論がしたい

Tags: python3, chainer

最近機械学習の勉強を始めました。友達に勧められchainerを使っています。
今は特にCNNについて勉強しています。学習はGPUなどがないと厳しそうなので、CIFAR-10のデータセットとModel zooにある学習済みCNNのcaffemodelを用いてとりあえず推論だけさせてみたいのですが、推論の方法を調べても学習の過程でさせているものが多く困っています。推論だけする方法を教えてほしいです。

使おうと思っているcaffemodelのリンクを以下に貼ります。
https://github.com/Coderx7/SimpNet/blob/master/SimpNetV2/Pretrained%20Models/CIFAR10/5/Cifar10_model.caffemodel

Comment: この記事が参考になるかもしれません。 [Chainerでcaffemodelを読み込んで画像を分類する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/dsanno/items/2c9ccfc53b5019475e0e)

Comment: 質問に不明瞭な点があるので，お伺いしてもよいでしょうか．目的は「学習済みの『caffemodelを使って』推論を行うこと」なのでしょうか．それとも「学習済みモデルを使って推論を行うこと」なのでしょうか．~~もし後者であるならば，Chainerには「Chainerらしい」学習済みモデルがあり，それを使ったほうがいろいろ簡単で，かつ勉強にもなると思います．~~SimpNetをどうしても使わなければいけない事情があるのであれば，PicoSushiさんが言うように，Caffeのコンバータを通す必要があると思いますが，CaffeのモデルはCaffe以外でまともに動かないので，素直に開発者(Coderx7)と同じバージョンのCaffeを使うのが良いと思います．（Caffeには独自拡張が多く，『共通のCaffe』は存在しないため）

Comment: 返信が遅くなり、申し訳ありません。

Comment: 様々な学習済みモデルで推論処理をしてみたかったので、ceffemodelを使おうと思っていました。chainerの学習済みモデルはModel zooほど種類がなさそうだったので。Cifar-10を使って学習したもので推論させてみたかっただけなので特にSimpNetにこだわりがあったわけではありません。素直にcaffeではなくchainerを使ったのは友達に「chainerは日本人が多く使っているので日本語の解説記事がたくさんあるし、可読性が良いので初心者でも使いやすい」と言われたからです。とりあえずアドバイス通りにchainerらしい学習済みモデルをつかって推論させてみたいと思います。アドバイスありがとうございました。

Comment: @asky もし回答が役立ったのであれば，upvote（回答の横の上三角）と解決済みフラグをお願いします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

結論から言えばできません．
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1K5QHLIYiqAAqwKOU26yFWevNbqKo0ruL

SimpNetはCaffe自体に拡張がなされているようです．